# Spark Structured Streaming Batch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am running batch in Structured programming of Spark. The below snippet code throws error saying "kafka is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source;". The version I am using for the same is --> spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark
    .read()         
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "*****")
    .option("subscribePattern", "test.*")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
    .load();
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: kafka is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source.;
```

Comment: Try to use `sql-kafka-0-10_2.11`, not `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10`.

Comment: What Spark version do you use? How do you execute the above code? In `spark-shell` or as part of a Spark application? How do you execute the Spark application?

Comment: Jacek, I use Spark 2.1.0 version. I am not using spark-shell for now. I just running the main class from eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and like me you are using read instead of readStream.

Changing `spark.read()` to `spark.readStream` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `spark-submit` mechanism and pass along `-jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar`

Adjust the version of kafka, scala and spark in that library according to ur own situation.